# On deriving the slope of a line

Tags: trigonometry, slope

A question with $x$ and $y$ each defined parametrically in $\theta$ requires you to calculate the slope of the normal to the curve at $\theta$. I've got $\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan\theta$, so the slope of normal is $-\cot\theta= \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$.

Now the answer is that the normal makes an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta$ with the $x$-axis, but how is this technically correct? If $\theta$ was $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, for instance, saying that it makes $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ would be incorrect, right? The slope of the normal would be $1$, and it'd make an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with the $x$-axis, wouldn't it?

Comment: A line that makes an angle of $\pi/4$ with the $x$-axis *also* can be said to make an angle of $5\pi/4$ with the $x$-axis. After all, $\tan(\pi/4)=\tan(5\pi/4)=1$.

Comment: The tan values are the same, but the angles aren't.

Comment: I didn't suggest that the angles were *the same*, rather that a line that makes one of them with the $x$-axis *also* makes the other. If we were talking about *rays*, things would be different. But since a line can be viewed as a pair of *opposite rays*, "the angle with the $x$-axis" is an ambiguous phrase.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right.